# How to repeat automatically seamless pattern in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

*This is basically the same question [as I asked recently](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103818/how-to-repeat-automatically-seamless-pattern-in-photoshop/), but about Illustrator, instead of Photoshop.*

Let's say I already have a seamless pattern. For example this one:
[image]

I'd like to quickly repeat it 4 times.

So the result would be:

*(pardon for scaling)*
[image]

Is there any automated way to do this in Illustrator, instead of resizing the workspace then copying and placing it three more times?

Answer (score 4):

Drag the artwork the **Swatch Panel** and it will create a pattern.

Double-click the swatch in the Swatch Panel to bring up the **Pattern Editor** in order to refine if necessary.

More info is available in the Help files: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may find your answer on the SuperUser resource. I did a quick search of Matrix copy Illustrator and picked the [top search result](https://superuser.com/questions/113186/best-way-to-create-an-array-of-objects-in-illustrator).

Effectively, you're telling the program to duplicate the object a certain number of times along x and a certain number of times along y, with appropriate spacing to accomplish your objective.